# Another exception was thrown: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

getting this error showing in red screen I update my packages
_TypeError Another exception was thrown: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' I tried to update the sdk  and I'm not understanding where the problem is in this code. I added CircularProgressIndicator with condition statements
The relevant error-causing widget was:
quizpage
quizpage:file:///C:/Users/flutt/Downloads/quiz/flutter-quizstar-master/lib/quizpage.dart:57:18

```
  class getjson extends StatefulWidget {
    
      String langname;
      getjson(this.langname);
    
      @override
      State<getjson> createState() => _getjsonState();
    }
    
    class _getjsonState extends State<getjson> {
      late String assettoload;
    
      // a function
      setasset() {
        if (widget.langname == "Science") {
          assettoload = "assets/Science.json";
        } else if (widget.langname == "Maths") {
          assettoload = "assets/Maths.json";
        } else if (widget.langname == "History") {
          assettoload = "assets/History.json";
        } 
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        setasset();
        // and now we return the FutureBuilder to load and decode JSON
        return FutureBuilder(
          future:
              DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List mydata = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
            if (mydata == null) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Loading",
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
            }}
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class quizpage extends StatefulWidget {
      final List mydata;
    
      quizpage({required this.mydata});
      @override
      _quizpageState createState() => _quizpageState(mydata);
    }
    
    class _quizpageState extends State<quizpage> {
      final List mydata;
      _quizpageState(this.mydata);
    
      Color colortoshow = Colors.indigoAccent;
      Color right = Colors.green;
      Color wrong = Colors.red;
      int marks = 0;
      int i = 1;
      bool disableAnswer = false;
      int j = 1;
      int timer = 30;
      String showtimer = "30";
      var random_array;
    
      Map<String, Color> btncolor = {
        "a": Colors.indigoAccent,
        "b": Colors.indigoAccent,
        "c": Colors.indigoAccent,
        "d": Colors.indigoAccent,
      };
    
      bool canceltimer = false;
    
    
      genrandomarray(){
        var distinctIds = [];
        var rand = new Random();
          for (int i = 0;; ) {
          distinctIds.add(rand.nextInt(10));
            random_array = distinctIds.toSet().toList();
            if(random_array.length < 10){
              continue;
            }else{
              break;
            }
          }
          print(random_array);
      }
   
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        starttimer();
        genrandomarray();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void setState(fn) {
        if (mounted) {
          super.setState(fn);
        }
      }
    
      void starttimer() async {
        const onesec = Duration(seconds: 1);
        Timer.periodic(onesec, (Timer t) {
          setState(() {
            if (timer < 1) {
              t.cancel();
              nextquestion();
            } else if (canceltimer == true) {
              t.cancel();
            } else {
              timer = timer - 1;
            }
            showtimer = timer.toString();
          });
        });
      }
    
      void nextquestion() {
        canceltimer = false;
        timer = 30;
        setState(() {
          if (j < 10) {
            i = random_array[j];
            j++;
          } else {
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => resultpage(marks: marks),
            ));
          }
          btncolor["a"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
          btncolor["b"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
          btncolor["c"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
          btncolor["d"] = Colors.indigoAccent;
          disableAnswer = false;
        });
        starttimer();
      }
    
      void checkanswer(String k) {
        
        // in the previous version this was
        // mydata[2]["1"] == mydata[1]["1"][k]
        // which i forgot to change
        // so nake sure that this is now corrected
        if (mydata[2][i.toString()] == mydata[1][i.toString()][k]) {
          // just a print sattement to check the correct working
          // debugPrint(mydata[2][i.toString()] + " is equal to " + mydata[1][i.toString()][k]);
          marks = marks + 5;
          // changing the color variable to be green
          colortoshow = right;
        } else {
          // just a print sattement to check the correct working
          // debugPrint(mydata[2]["1"] + " is equal to " + mydata[1]["1"][k]);
          colortoshow = wrong;
        }
        setState(() {
          btncolor[k] = colortoshow;
          canceltimer = true;
          disableAnswer = true;
        });
        // nextquestion();
        // changed timer duration to 1 second
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), nextquestion);
      }
    
      Widget choicebutton(String k) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 10.0,
            horizontal: 20.0,
          ),
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => checkanswer(k),
            child: Text(
              mydata[1][i.toString()][k],
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: "Alike",
                fontSize: 16.0,
              ),
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
            color: btncolor[k],
            splashColor: Colors.indigo[700],
            highlightColor: Colors.indigo[700],
            minWidth: 200.0,
            height: 45.0,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
            [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async{
            return await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      title: Text(
                        "Welcome",
                      ),
                      content: Text("You Can't Go Back At This Stage."),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'Ok',
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ));
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      mydata[0][i.toString()] ,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontFamily: "Quando",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 6,
                    child: AbsorbPointer(
                      absorbing: disableAnswer,
                        child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            choicebutton('a'),
                            choicebutton('b'),
                            choicebutton('c'),
                            choicebutton('d'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        showtimer,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 35.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontFamily: 'Times New Roman',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code some place your are show some variable in `Text` widget that might be `null` so change them to these:

```
Text(
  mydata[1][i.toString()][k] ?? "",//<--- add this
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: "Alike",
    fontSize: 16.0,
  ),
  maxLines: 1,
)
```

and

```
Expanded(
  flex: 3,
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    child: Text(
      mydata[0][i.toString()] ?? "",//<--- add this
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        fontFamily: "Quando",
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out @binoarin

Comment: i change my code but the another error is showing     Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.

Comment: could you print("mydata = $mydata"); add the first line of build method? @binoarin

Comment: no I don't know about this method

Comment: @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
            [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
        print("mydata = $mydata"); // put it here and tell me the result

Comment: same error i added this line

Comment: I know, could you show me the print result in your debug console?

Comment: 'The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building quizpage(dirty, state: _quizpageState#0e809):  
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("a")

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  quizpage
  quizpage:file:///C:/Users/flutt/Downloads/quiz/flutter-quizstar-master/lib/quizpage.dart:57:18   '

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your expression is evaluating to null in Text() Widget,
just put some constant strings in text widgets and try to run.
if expression is evaluating to null, use **??** operation to provide default string value to Text Widget.